node:events:491 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ^
`node:events:491
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^
Error: spawn /opt/alt/alt-nodejs19/root/usr/bin/node EAGAIN
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:285:19)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:483:16)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:483:16)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
errno: -11,
code: 'EAGAIN',
syscall: 'spawn /opt/alt/alt-nodejs19/root/usr/bin/node',
path: '/opt/alt/alt-nodejs19/root/usr/bin/node',
spawnargs: [
'/home/desmoricambi/nodevenv/public_html/node/19/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js'
]
}
`
What is the solution of following error? I already deleted node_modules and applied npm i
This issue is plaguing me when I try to run a build in production, while locally everything works fine. I am no longer able to deploy an updated build on my host because of this error. And if I try to build locally and then upload the .next folder to production, it returns error 503

Needs more information, version of nextjs, how to reproduce, what did you change that made this error pop up? Downloading a fresh version of nextjs does not give this error so no one knows how to help you

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@Will40
Next: 11.1.2
the error occurs during the production build
this issue is plaguing me when I try to run a build in production, while locally everything works fine. I am no longer able to deploy an updated build on my host because of this error. And if I try to build locally and then upload the .next folder to production, it returns error 503

Sounds like something is wrong with your production setup, still no one would be able to help you with this little information

I solved it by doing a clean install of node via cPanel, and redeploying.
